# SVI Parametrization: simple example does not work

Tags: matlab, calibration, curve-fitting

I'm trying to experiment with the SVI model. I use the following scripts:

```
a = 0.05;
b = 0.3;
rho = -0.35;
m = 0;
sigma = 0.15; 

S0 = 100;
r = 0.033;
q = 0.0022; 
T = 0.26; 
F0 = S0*exp((r-q)*T);
k = (50:0.5:120);

iv = a+b*(rho*(k-m)+((k-m).^2+sigma^2).^(1/2)); 
plot(log(k/F0),(iv/T).^(1/2));
```

Matlab returns me the following:
[image]

What is the problem here? It doesn't work while it is simply fitting the parametrization.

Comment: $F_t$ is forward price process of the underlying $S_t$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, sorry for not mentioning. I'm just frustrated because it is something really silly that I do not see.

Comment: Indeed, $\operatorname{Imp}(x)=a+b(\rho(x-m)\sqrt {(x-m)^2+\sigma^2})$ where $x$ is  moneyness.

Comment: i.e $x=\log\left(\frac{K}{F}\right)$

Comment: Other moneynesses can be defined, such as the underlying
log-moneyness.

Comment: Sorry , $\operatorname{Imp}(x)=a+b(\rho(x-m)+\sqrt{(x-m)^2+\sigma^2})$ where $x$ is  moneyness.

Comment: All right, I forgot the log-moneyless. How do I retrieve the actual implied volatilities then?

Comment: total implied variance for a fixed time to maturity?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how do I retrieve the implied volatilities from the total implied variance? I could just divided by $T$ and take the square root as in my code. But those are not really implied volatilities as it is a function of the log-moneyness as you suggested.

Comment: Why?????????????

Comment: Because implied volatilities should not be greater than one.

Comment: Note, your parameters are not calibrated, becase $$2\min\{x_i\}\le m \le2\max\{x_i\}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44094/discussion-between-user39039-and-behrouz-maleki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 0.05;
b = 0.3;
rho = -0.35;
m = 0;
sigma = 0.15; 
S0 = 100;
r = 0.033;
q = 0.0022; 
T = 0.26; 
F0 = S0*exp((r-q)*T);
k = (50:0.5:120);
x=log(k/F0);
iv = a+b*(rho*(x-m)+((x-m).^2+sigma^2).^(1/2)); 
plot(x,(iv/T).^(1/2));
```

[image]